# Комментарии, оставляемые препроцессором

Tags: c++, gcc

После препроцессирования исходного файла. Например такого

```
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

получается

```
# 1 "main.cpp"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "main.cpp"

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Так вот, что значит `# 1 "main.cpp"`, `# 1 "<built-in>"`, `# 1 "<command-line>"`,`# 1 "main.cpp"`?
Читал про препроцессор, ничего не нашел по этому поводу.

PS: Суть в том, что я хочу написать свой компилятор С++, а начать естественно с препроцессора так как это сама простая часть. Какой то сверх задачи не стоит, просто ради развлечения. И естественно, проверять препроцессор хотелось бы сразу. До того как я напишу всё. Отсюда и такой странный вопрос о препроцессоре.
Ну и конечно я не планирую реализовывать все что есть в компиляторе. Только минимум.

Comment: Это внутренние служебные пометки, никакого отнощения к языку не имеющие.

Comment: @AnT Они не влияют на компиляцию? Если я их допустим удалю и попытаюсь скомпилировать код без них, у меня это получится?

Comment: Может получится, может не получится - это внутреннее дело конкретной реализации. В языке С++ нет возможности влезть и что-то поменять между препроцессором и собственно компилятором. Если вы будете туда лезть и что-то менять - что-то может сломаться.

Comment: @AnT Да я понимаю, но в данном конкретном случае все получилось. Суть в том что, я хочу написать свой компилятор с++, а начать естественно с препроцессора так как это сама простая часть. Какой то сверх задачи не стоит, просто ради развлечения. И естественно, проверять препроцессор хотелось бы сразу. До того как я напишу всё. Отсюда и такой странный вопрос о препроцессоре.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

В стандарте С++ этого нет.

Насколько я знаю, GCC использует эти отметки только для того, чтобы в сообщениях об ошибках (и предупреждениях) номера строк и названия файлов были правильные.

То есть чтобы номера строк соответствовали коду до препроцессирования, а не после. И если ошибка случилась в заинклуженом файле, чтобы это было указано в сообщении об ошибке.

Пример:

```cpp
# 100 "foo.cpp"

int main()
{
    f
}
```

На этот код GCC выдает:

```
foo.cpp:103:5: error: 'f' was not declared in this scope
```

Смотрите, название файла и номер строки он взял не настоящие, а такие, как было указано после `#`.